# react component load 5 times 'undefined' then it finds the inner html div

Tags: reactjs, innerhtml, advertisement-server, use-ref

emphasized text

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from "react";
import Axios from "./axios.js";


//ADblockerdetection
export  function Adblockerdetection() {
    const [firstname, setfirstname] = useState('');

    const [adblock, adblocdetected] = useState(false);

 Axios.get("/user").then((result) => {
       setfirstname(
       result.data.firstname
           );
         }); 

    useEffect(() => {
        return Adblockerdetection();
    });
  
 
    function Adblockerdetection() {
        const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

        const noadblock = () => {
            adblocdetected(false);
        };

        const adblocker = () => {
            adblocdetected(true);
        };

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = "adblock-detection";
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "./public/gpt.js";
        script.onload = noadblock;
        script.onerror = adblocker;
        head.appendChild(script);

        //this.adblocdetected() = this.adblocdetected().bind(this);
    }
    return (
        <div>
           
            <div className="AdblockerMessage">
                {adblock ? (<div className="modal1">
                    <div id="adblock_message" >
                        <h2>HELLO {firstname}</h2>
                        <p>it looks like you are using an Adblocker. <br/>Please disable
                        the adblocker for this page!</p>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                Adblockerdetection( window.location.reload(true));
                            }}
                        >
                          
                        try to proof of Adblocker
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                   null
                )}
           
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default function Adinjection(props) {
    const { adtype, zoneid, id, name } = props;
        var therealURL =
        "https://marcpassenheim.net/AdServerTest/www/delivery/afr.php?";
    var theRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
    var urlparam = {
        zoneid: zoneid,
        cb: theRandom,
    };
    var theURL = Object.keys(urlparam)
        .map((key) => key + "=" + urlparam[key])
        .join("&");
    //the adurl
    var construUrl = therealURL + theURL;
//------USEstat--------------------------------------------


//----------------------------------------

    const ads = {
        bigsky: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "160" + "px",
            height: "600" + "px",
        },
        sky: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "120" + "px",
            height: "600" + "px",
        },

        billboard: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "800" + "px",
            height: "250" + "px",
        },
        bigbillboard: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "970" + "px",
            height: "250" + "px",
        },
        mediumrectangle: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "300" + "px",
            height: "250" + "px",
        },
        hpa: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            src: construUrl,
            width: "300" + "px",
            height: "600" + "px",
        },
    };
    //Component where the ADTYPE prop is overgiven
    const currentAd = ads[adtype];

 //----------------HIDETheSpots-------------------------
const [visible, setAdSpotvisible] = useState(false);

 useEffect( () => {
  
      return setAdSpotvisible(true);
 }, []);

//setthecomponent to display:none when its not loaded
const divStyleNone = {
 display: "none !important",
 height:0+'px !important',
 width:0+'px !important'
};
const divstyleBlock = {
 display: "block",
 background: "yellow",
 height:'auto',
 width:'auto'
 
};



const [iframe,stateiframe] =useState(<iframe/>)
const containerToProof = useRef()

const isEmpty = containerToProof.current;
if(isEmpty==='undefined'){
       console.log('allo')
}
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('saysomething',isEmpty)   
    },[<iframe/>]);


    return (
        <div>
           <div  ref={containerToProof}  >

               {visible ? (<div style={divstyleBlock}>
                            <iframe
                                id={currentAd.id}
                                name={currentAd.name}
                                src={currentAd.src}
                                frameBorder="no"
                                scrolling="no"
                                width={currentAd.width}
                                height={currentAd.height}
                                allow="autoplay"
                               
                                
                            />
                        </div>):( <div style={divStyleNone}> </div>)
              
              
              
               }
        </div>
        </div>
    );







    
}
```

hi im trying to to proof the response of an adserver. To check which typeof response it is im using useRef() and the reference on the div where the iframe will be constructed and send the get request to the adserverhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/3kvMo.png

the ads object looks like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe3aL.png

everytime im refresh the page the console.log statement 'saysomething' gives me 5 times an  undefined and then it finds the divs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V5bX.png

```
5adinjection.js:171 saysomething undefined
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
adinjection.js:171 saysomething <div>​…​</div>​
```

The problem is i need the innerHTML Value immediately to work with the stored value otherwise, when im trying to go on in an if statement or something different the console say 'can't find value of undefined blah blah....' Did i missed something im stuck here for hour s and need help.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please update your question with a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the [<>] toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)
In general, please post code, error messages, markup, etc. as text, not as a picture of text. Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to run `Adblockerdetection()` only after the first mount. For this you need to pass empty array to `useEffect` dependency. Also async functions should be inside useEffect.

```
    useEffect(() => {
       Axios.get("/user").then(result => {
          setfirstname(result.data.firstname);
       });
       return Adblockerdetection();
     }, []);
```

Also you are getting `undefined` because the value of `containerToProof.current` is assigned only once to `isEmpty` variable. So instead of doing `console.log('saysomething',isEmpty)` change to `console.log('saysomething',containerToProof.current)` inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('saysomething',containerToProof.current)   
 },[<iframe/>]);
```

To check if iframe is loaded

```
<div ref={containerToProof}>
          {visible ? (
            <div style={divstyleBlock}>
              <iframe
                id={currentAd.id}
                name={currentAd.name}
                src={currentAd.src}
                frameBorder="no"
                scrolling="no"
                width={currentAd.width}
                height={currentAd.height}
                allow="autoplay"
                onLoad={() => {
                  // iframe is loaded now and here you can call the function
                }}
              />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div style={divStyleNone}> </div>
          )}
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response but this is not solving my problem. the main problem is that useRef is not finding the div immediately the console.log says 5 times undefined and the he finds the ref container

Comment: @p-heim Have updated the answer, with the reason for getting undefined.

Comment: @ Jagrati that helps a lot thanks but now the useeffect is repeating it 3 times. Now i have the div directly but to much 'answers'. i integrated the function call too the other component 5 times not 15. ... can you explain why he is 3times repeating it

Comment: i cant upload a picture to show the output of conole.log

Comment: @p-heim are you using `<React.StrictMode>`?. Also even if u are not using it.. then you will get 2 console logs, first is when the div mounts, and second is when iframe is loaded.

Comment: hey Jagrati that was the pitfall  if got an other questions related to the iframe. If im trying to check if the value of containerToProof now is an iframe the they are not cheking it right i know that it is always an iframe but im not sure how to test it  ````

Comment: ```
 var isiframe = containerToProof.current.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
console.log('isiframe', isiframe);


    if(isiframe.typeOf=== iframe){
        console.log('allo')
        setAdSpotvisible(true)
    
    }else{

        setAdSpotvisible(false)
    }

Comment: You can actully use onLoad function of `iframe` to setAdSpotvisible

Comment: i tried many different syntaxes in /single qoutes/ double quotes /in html tag/ html tag in double quotes / and so on but nothing really worked

Comment: Yes thats right but sometimes it isnt an iframe it is a 1x1 pixel and it would be nice to proof is it an iframe or not  /if not   > adspotvisible false

Comment: <React.StrictMode> isnt working where should i place it ?

Comment: should i pace it inside the return ? or where ?

Comment: hey @Jagrati im a bit further i'm now holding the iframe in a variable and i have to check if iframe is loaded i tried many different things but i cant solve the problem to check if iframe is loaded `````  useEffect(()=>{
   const isiframe = myRef.current;
    console.log('isifsdsadasrame',isiframe)
  
    isiframe.onload = function() {
        alert('myframe is loaded'); };

    function iframisloaded (){
        console.log('myframe is loaded');
      };

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your actual issue, but I have updated the answer, considering that you want to call some function, when iframe gets loaded

Comment: and how can i check    what kind of type holds  inside a variable i tried something like this       useEffect(() => {
        const isiframe = myRef.current;
        console.log('isiframe', isiframe.tagName);


        if(isiframe==='iframe'){
     console.log('iframe')
     setAdSpotvisible(false);
        }

    }, [myRef]);

Comment: i didn't mentioned you in my previously post

Comment: maybe you have some time to have look at this question. That would be really helpful to me:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627655/change-the-state-randomly-of-two-divs-with-usestate-in-react-component-random