# change the state randomly of two divs with useState in react component / random number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two divs with Ads on the same spot of a component. Both of them have a  prop called decesionmaker1 and decesionmaker2.

```
<div className="billboard">
    <Adinjection
        adtype="billboard"
        configobject={Siteconfig.userfinder.billboard}
        decisionmaker2={true}
    />
</div>

<div className="bigbillboard">
    <Adinjection
        adtype="bigbillboard"
        configobject={Siteconfig.userfinder.bigbillboard}
        decisionmaker1={true}
    />
</div>
```

Both props are true (decesionmaker2={true}).  I overgive this props to the "controll component". Then im have a the following useState

```
const [ showbillboard, setshowbillboard ] = useState(false);
```

With this useState and a randomnumber which i store in a variable

```
const thesecrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
```

im trying to, depending on the value of the randomnumber, to set the state randomly on one of the divs to display them randomly:
The useeffect looks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("thesecrandom", thesecrandom);
    if (thesecrandom > 5) {
        if (decisionmaker1) {
            setshowbillboard(true);
            setAdSpotvisible(true);
        } else if (thesecrandom < 5) {
            if (decisionmaker2) {
                setshowbillboard(true);
                setAdSpotvisible(true);
            } else {
                setshowbillboard(true);
            }
        }
    } else {
        setshowbillboard(true);
    }

    if (scrollactiv) {
        window.onscroll = () => {
            //setOffset(window.pageYOffset)
            if (window.pageYOffset > 1200) {
                setAdSpotvisible(true);
                setshowbecause(true);
            } else {
                setAdSpotvisible(true);
                setshowbecause(false);
            }
        };
    } else {
        setshowbecause(true);
    }
}, []);
```

the return statement looks:

```
return (
    <div>
        {visible && showbecause && showbillboard ? (
            <div style={divstyleBlock}>
                <iframe
                    id={configobject.id}
                    name={configobject.name}
                    src={currentAd.src}
                    frameBorder="no"
                    scrolling="no"
                    width={configobject.width}
                    height={configobject.height}
                    allow="autoplay"
                    ref={(el) => (myRef.current = el)}
                    onLoad={(onload) => {
                        // console.log("the frame is loaded ");
                        setAdSpotvisible(true);
                    }}
                    onError={(onerror) => {
                        // console.log("my fram is not  loaded ");
                        setAdSpotvisible(false);
                        head1a.appendChild(Pixelscript);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div style={divStyleNone} ref={(el) => (mySecREf.current = el)} />
        )}

        <Adblockerdetection />
    </div>
);
```

With this code the display state of every other ad on the  component is also displaying randomly. itried over hours a lot of other combinations of the if statement on decisionmaker1+decisionmaker2 and but i can't find a solution. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to randomly show either `.billboard` or `.bigbillboard`? But what I'm sure of is that this line: `window.onscroll = () => {` inside your component is deadly.

Comment: hi thomas yes i want to show .bigbillboard and billboard randomly. With this code every  the ad on the site are are showing randomly. I want to show only the mentioned two randomly not very one else.  The window. onscroll is working fine and there is nothing to customize there. i posted it only  for completeness

Comment: both of them randomly, or either one or the other?

Comment: I would like to either one or the other to be displayed.  currently the code changes the state of  every ad on the site and display it randomly

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to either one or the other to be displayed.

then you should not manage this inside the component itself. Especially as you only need this in that one place

```
const bigbillboard = React.useMemo(() => Math.random() < 0.5, []);

{ bigbillboard ? (
    <div className="bigbillboard">
        <Adinjection 
            adtype="bigbillboard" 
            configobject={Siteconfig.userfinder.bigbillboard} 
        />
    </div>
) : (
    <div className="billboard">
        <Adinjection 
            adtype="billboard" 
            configobject={Siteconfig.userfinder.billboard} 
        />
    </div>
) }
```

and about `window.onscroll`

> The window. onscroll is working fine and there is nothing to customize there.

The next instance that tags along may overwrite your scroll-handler. Or you implement another scroll handler the same way in another *(completely unrelated)* component and it overwrites this one, now go on and debug that. Better write it that way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!scrollactiv) {
        setshowbecause(true);
        return;
    }

    const handler = () => {
        //setOffset(window.pageYOffset)
        if (window.pageYOffset > 1200) {
            setAdSpotvisible(true);
            setshowbecause(true);
        } else {
            setAdSpotvisible(true);
            setshowbecause(false);
        }
    };

    addEventListener("scroll", handler);

    // And remove your event-listener when they are no longer needed;
    // or the component unmounts.
    // That's something you didn't do either.
    return () => {
        removeEventListener("scroll", handler);
    };
}, [scrollactiv]);
```

Comment: thanks  i will try this and com back to you in a minute

Comment: HI @thomas is there a way to  manage the display of the billboard and the bigbillboard from the other component. like i tried it?